# shipping method name alias

Tags: magento-1.8, checkout, shipping-methods, magento-1.9

I'm trying to setup shipping method aliases for the checkout process.

for example for USPS, instead of the end-user seeing

"Priority Mail 1-Day Small Flat Rate Box"

I'd like to display

"Standard Ground"

thanks

Comment: you have to create new Shipping method?

Comment: http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/change-shipping-price-handling-fee-fly-magento/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution would be overriding the template file:

in case of the rwd (Magento 1.9.0.1)  you can find it here :
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml

Around line 58 you can find following code:

```
<label for="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getMethodTitle()) ?>
```

the important part of it is :

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getMethodTitle()) ?>
```

Now you can replace it with your logic for example  :

```
<?php if($_rate->getMethodTitle() == 'blalalalala'): ?>
 <?php echo 'yourName'; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope my answer helped you.

Comment: this worked .  thank you.  I did add <?php else : echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getMethodTitle()) ?>

Comment: For a cleaner solution, use Magento's built in translation functionality and add the translation to your translation file, e.g:

`<?php echo $this->__($this->escapeHtml($_rate->getMethodTitle())) ?>`

Answer (score 2):

Looking through the USPS code it appears that all the titles are passed through the Magento translation tool. If this is the case you should be able to simply add them to your theme's translation file. This will save you having to edit any code or templates to change the title of the method.

Answer (score 2):

Just update it in the locale file, you can change any text like this.

Zero code.

Comment: The locale file doesn't work for USPS, the correct and elegant answer is here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37130/override-usps-shipping-method-name

Comment: Yes it does, just tried it: http://grab.by/C13M and http://grab.by/C13O - you need to do in Mage_Usa.csv

Answer (score 0):

Goto and copy `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Progress.php`  copy to

```
app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Progress.php
```

And edit function

```
 public function getShippingDescription()
    {
      if($this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod()=='flatrate_flatrate'){ 
return "MY Flat rate";

  }
 // this type of condition here
        return $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingDescription();
    }
```