# How to remove transit time from USPS

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm a newbie at Magento and wanted to remove the USPS transit time.  I followed your suggestions below, but am not sure how to add appropriate translations into the Mage_Shipping.csv file.  Could you clarify?  Thanks.

[override USPS shipping method name](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37130/override-usps-shipping-method-name)

Answer (score 1):

```
"First-Class Mail Parcel","First-Class Mail (3-5 Days)"
"Priority Mail 1-Day","Priority Mail (2-3 Days)"
"Priority Mail 2-Day","Priority Mail (2-3 Days)"
"Priority Mail 3-Day","Priority Mail (2-3 Days)"
"Priority Mail Express 2-Day","Priority Mail Express (1-2 Days)"
"Priority Mail Express 1-Day","Priority Mail Express (1-2 Days)"
```

Posting here because I couldn't find this information myself.
We added that above to the bottom of our `Mage_Shipping.csv` file.

It took us forever to find out because we forgot to flush cache storage after adding those lines. 
(We added in the 3-5days bit, you can remove it if you'd like)